# Displaying information about the exception in a custom 500 error jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, custom-error-pages

I would like :

- to customize my `500 error` page and
- log the exception details that caused the 500,

**is there a way to get this info? how do I reference it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify error page in **web.xml** like this

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Then create **error500.jsp** as error page, use `exception` object to display the stacktrace like this.

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<% exception.printStackTrace(response.getWriter()); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me without forcing the actual error 500, but rather a custom error page, with only my output:

**Main.jsp**

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
<... your code ...>
```

**Error.jsp**

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
<% response.setStatus(200,""); %>
Server Error 500: Error text ...
```